# How to handle external popup using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

In my project, there has one advertisement provider who shows us pop up advertisement but Problem is this pop-up will come it's not fixed.Sometimes add not show sometimes comes this pop up after 1 minute and interrupts my test case.

I write a code for close this popup but it's not a perfect solution I think..If anyone can help?

```
boolean Imclose = wd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='IM_overlay_close_container IM_overlay_close_button']")).isDisplayed();
    if (Imclose == true) {
        wd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='IM_overlay_close_container IM_overlay_close_button']")).click();
    }
```

Comment: use alert interface

Comment: can you please show me any example?

Comment: Is this site public, so that I can have a look to exactly what you are dealing with and it will be easier to help you out. I am assuming, the pop-up might not be an alert after all, instead an iframe/modal.

Comment: You are right it's not alert.Please go www.rentbyowner.com/usa You can check here..

Comment: It is a an ad pop up s you have to wait and then click on close or X

Comment: Can you please check my code if I did any mistake.if popup not open its shows element not visible

Comment: actually problem is that ad is displayed after some time so it is quite difficult to isdisplayed() use here, also when i click on close it open a new window. Some time it closed it

Answer (score 1):

Try these code, to handle the unwanted pop up page. I have provided 180 seconds of wait. Then Click on close button inside the advertisement pop up page.

After click on advertisement pop up page, another window is getting open, So I have to redirect to my main window, then only further code will execute.

```
driver.get("https://www.rentbyowner.com/usa");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    try
    {           
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 180);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'IM_overlay_foreground')]"))));
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'IM_overlay_foreground')]//span[@class='IM_close_text']")).click();


            try
            {
                String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();
                for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles())
                {
                    driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
                    //driver.switchTo().window(winHandle).close();
                }
                driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore);

                //Verify purpose written code, weather my driver is getting move to parent window or not.

                WebDriverWait element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
                element.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.id("top_k_search"))));
                driver.findElement(By.id("top_k_search")).clear();
                System.out.println("Try block");
            }
             catch(Exception a)
            {
                 System.out.println("Inner Catch");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Element not present");
            //Provide your code here..
        }
```

Comment: **new window's handle is not switched to, when 'Close' button is clicked. The focus is entirely on parent/main window.** But, if you want to close the new/child window, you would be using the code as above to switch and close it. But, the main purpose of closing of popup is already handled in the first 3 lines of code in the outer `try-catch block`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Subh. But somehow pop up page is not getting closed, So I try this solution.

Comment: Tell you what, put a breakpoint on the execution just before clicking the close button. Now, click the close button manually; you would notice the button getting clicked, the pop-up getting closed, and new window getting opened simultaneously. :)  **Note-** The pop-up and the New Window are separate entities by the way.

Comment: Please Mark this answer as `Accepted`, if it's work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I observed that this is a normal pop-up overlay over the webpage and not an alert and it appears almost within 60 seconds. So, the below code might just work for you.

```
//Waiting for the Popup to appear
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,60);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'IM_overlay_foreground')]")));

//Clicking on the 'Close' text to close the popup.
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'IM_overlay_foreground')]//span[@class='IM_close_text']")).click();
```

**NOTE:** You can increase the time from 60 to 90, in case it appears to take longer. Thing is, whenever the popup appears within the timeframe set, it is handled(as in Closed).

Comment: I have tried your code, but it's not working to close the pop up page, I have also provided the wait for 180 seconds, then pop up page is showing, but when i try to click on close button or text, it simply open the another browser window.

Comment: @Jainish, Thanks for the check and analysis. I didn't had resources at the time to see this through.:) When 'Close' button is clicked, it actually closes the pop-up and opens a new window simultaneously. The above line of code actually does the same what OP has asked. Closing new window is just an option. Please find further clarifications in the comments section of your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Actually it is coming after 30-50 seconds so you have to wait and then click on close button.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\software and tools\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.rentbyowner.com/usa");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
WebElement ad=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='IM_target_overlay']/div/div/div/div[1]/a/div"));
WebDriverWait wait= new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(ad));
ad.click();
```

Refer this link for more information:

[Handling Alerts in Selenium Webdriver](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/handling-of-alerts-javascript-alerts-and-popup-boxes/)

Comment: I have tried your code, but it's not working to close the pop up page, I have also provided the wait for `180` seconds, then pop up page is showing, but when i try to click on close button or text, it simply open the another browser  window.

Comment: Kindly provide solution then, as it is worked in my pc